# svn: post commit hook

Tags: svn, hook, commit, visualsvn-server

We use VisualSVN Server for code syncronization... and I'd like to add some routine operations after each commit. They're quite usual...create directories, making zip backup and so on. so I wrote cmd script to do them but can't execute it. 
I did the following:
In Properties for my repository folder on the "Hooks" tab I wrote
1 call c:\script.cmd
2 c:\script.cmd
I also tried to use quotes...and wrote exit 0 at the end of the script, but it didn't help.

Is there an easy way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Any error codes?

Try testing out the scripts by running them from the command line.

Windows seems a lot more finicky about this and/or a lot less documentation, but try going into the actual repository via command line and edit the template post-commit hook to an actual hook and run it from the command line, what happens there?

as an aside, it's raises an eyebrow why you are trying to do so much in post commit hook.